# Running a particular task on airflow master node

Tags: airflow

I have a dag with a list of tasks that are run using the celery executor on different worker nodes. However I would like to run one of the tasks on the master node. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You are able to set specific tasks to listen to specific [queues in Celery](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/concepts.html?highlight=default_queue#queues). The airflow documentation covers it quite nicely but the gist of it is:

1. set a queue attribute on the operator representing the task you want to run on a specific node to a value different from the `celery -> default_queue` value in `airflow.cfg`
2. Run the worker process on your master node by specifying the queue it needs to listen on `airflow worker -q queue_name`. If you want your worker to listen to multiple queues, you can use a comma delimited list `airflow worker -q default_queue,queue_name`